# How to keep the parameter by default on python

Tags: python, function, parameters

I know that we can give the parameter to the function, and we can call the function without parameter:

```
def printWords(text1="a", text2="b"):
   print('The text1 is "%s" and text2 is "%s"' % (text1,text2))
    
printWords()
```

Then, We can get the result

```
The text1 is "a" and text2 is "b"
```

We also can pass the result to override the default parameter

```
printWords("Apple") // The text1 is "Apple" and text2 is "b"
printWords("Apple","Banana") // The text1 is "Apple" and text2 is "Banana"
```

Then, How to do if I only want to change the `text2` ?
In this case we can pass the `a` into the function.
But it is So messy if there are many parameters with long text, for example:

```
def curlSomthing(sslKey="MIICXAIBAAKBgQCRq88qPiw..............=",someText="BuDPuTMSUrwnophwzti8HRc6Z7SYaGnFHMVMrF/3f/TgdWd4UTH3397RA7m5I4gVNbFCA0xOTfh............",someSetting=False):
     ....
     ....
     ....
     ....
```

We can't copy and paste all the parameter every time we call the function.
I know this is not a good way to define a function.
But so many function like this in my company's code. I can't change all the function

Any solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the argument name as a keyword argument:

```
printWords(text2="Apple")
```

Then `text1` would remain the same.

With your other messy function:

```
curlSomthing(someText="foo bar")
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue of messy code and long text?

Comment: @PCM Edited my answer with an example of the messy code

Comment: I didn't get it. How is it different from what OP tried?

Comment: @PCM He want's to only modify a certain parameter, which is what I did...